# Sort arrays to make odds before evens

Tags: swift

Given an array and then sort it to make the odds appearance before evens.
So I wrote the method like below in Swift. I can't see anything wrong in this methods, but the logic is just not right.
Anybody could give me a clue will save my life.
Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

```
class OddsBeforeEvens {
    func sortArrayOddsBeforeEvens(var array: [Int]) -> [Int]? {
        if array.isEmpty { return nil }
        let length = array.count
        var begin = 0
        var end = length - 1
        var temp: Int
        while (begin < end) {
            while (begin < end && array[begin] / 2 != 0) {
                begin += 1
            }
            while (begin < end && array[end] / 2 == 0) {
                end -= 1
            }
            if (begin < end) {
                temp = array[begin]
                array[begin] = array[end]
                array[end] = temp
            }
        }

        return array
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* the code?

Comment: It seem that you have to use `% 2 != 0`instead of `/ 2 != 0` to detect if the number is odd or even.

Comment: @Hoa,thank you very much! I've made a terrible elementary mistake and i didn't find out for a long time! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative, you can separate the odds and even numbers by two `filter` operations on the array, and simply join the two resulting arrays, with the odd values arrays prior to the even values array

```
func sortArrayOddsBeforeEvens(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    let odds = array.filter{ $0 % 2 != 0 }
    let evens = array.filter{ $0 % 2 == 0 }
    return odds + evens
}     

print(sortArrayOddsBeforeEvens([1,4,3,7,8,11,12,27,18]))
// [1, 3, 7, 11, 27, 4, 8, 12, 18]
```

Or,

```
func sortArrayOddsBeforeEvens(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    return array.filter{ $0 % 2 != 0 } + array.filter{ $0 % 2 == 0 }
}     

print(sortArrayOddsBeforeEvens(array: [1,4,3,7,8,11,12,27,18]))
// [1, 3, 7, 11, 27, 4, 8, 12, 18]
```

---

This shouldn't be an issue in practice unless you're writing some HPC applications (in which case possible Swift isn't the optimal language of choice), but if you for some reason worry about performance wr.t. the two `filter` operations above, you could use the result of `$0 % 2` (which is always in the set `{0, 1}`) directly as an index to point at one of two given result arrays. E.g.

```
func sortArrayOddsBeforeEvens(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var arr: [[Int]] = [[],[]]
    array.forEach { arr[$0 % 2].append($0) }
    return arr[1] + arr[0]
} 

print(sortArrayOddsBeforeEvens([1,4,3,7,8,11,12,27,18]))
// [1, 3, 7, 11, 27, 4, 8, 12, 18]
```

Comment: This is great! I will keep it in my mind! Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by the Hoa answer, here is a sort method that will ensure you a "[strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings)". As a result, you will have all the odd values before then even ones. And inside each group, the values will be sorted.

```
let arr = [1,3,4,5,9,10,50,2,8,12,34,53,88,23]

let arrSorted  = arr.sort { (a, b) -> Bool in
    // If a and b are both even (or odd), we simply compare them
    if a % 2 == b % 2{
        return (b>a)
    }
    // Else, we just put the odd values first
    return a % 2 != 0
}
```

This example gives this result:

```
[1, 3, 5, 9, 23, 53, 2, 4, 8, 10, 12, 34, 50, 88]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sort`function in swift, like this:

```
let arr = [1,3,4,5,9,10,50,2,8,12,34,53,88,23]

let arrSorted  = arr.sort { (a, b) -> Bool in
    return a % 2 != 0
}
```

to get sorted odds and sorted evens:

```
let arrSorted  = arr.sort { (a, b) -> Bool in
    if (a % 2 != 0) {
        if (b % 2 != 0) {
            return a < b
        } else {
            return true
        }
    } else {
        return a < b
    }
}
```

Comment: That may work by chance, but your comparison function is not a "strict weak ordering" as required: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_MutableCollectionType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/MutableCollectionType/s:FEsPs21MutableCollectionType4sortFFTWx9Generator7Element_WxS0_S1___SbGSaWxS0_S1___

Answer (score 2):

While @dfri 's solution works well and looks much nicer than mine, the performance is 2n, meaning that filter loops through 
the array twice. If you're after performance you can use this code because it only loops through the array once so it should be twice as fast.

```
func sortArrayOddsBeforeEvens(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var odds = []
    var evens = []
    for int in array {
        if int % 2 == 0 {
            evens.append(int)
        } else {
            odds.append(int)
    }
    return odds + evens
}
```

Comment: This won't sort the numbers from smallest to largest.

Comment: Which is not requested by OP

Comment: I meant it as in, of course your's will be quicker when it doesn't do the same thing. Wasn't trying to say that you did this wrong - this is actually probably exactly what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go for high order functions.

```
func sortArrayOddsBeforeEvens(array: [Int]) -> [Int]? {
    if array.isEmpty { return nil }
    var array = array
    let length = array.count
    var begin = 0
    var end = length - 1
    var temp: Int
    while (begin < end) {
        while (begin < end && array[begin] % 2 == 1) {
            begin += 1
        }
        while (begin < end && array[end] % 2 == 0) {
            end -= 1
        }
        if (begin < end) {
            temp = array[begin]
            array[begin] = array[end]
            array[end] = temp
            begin += 1
            end -= 1
        }
    }
    return array
}
```